# Why do taxonomy_get_tree() & entity_load('taxonomy_term', etc..) give different counts?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm finding that I am missing some terms in a vocabulary when I try to get them all with `taxonomy_get_tree($vid)`.

If I verify the count of terms in the vocabulary by getting the count of `entity_load('taxonomy_term', FALSE, array('vid' => $vid))` when I compare the counts they are different.

Can anyone tell me why the counts would be different?

I was hoping to use `taxonomy_get_tree()` as it's much faster for the number of terms I have (> 10k) but it's useless if it's not going to deliver all terms.

Thanks for any info on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running some mysql queries on the taxonomy_term_data table it appears that the difference in counts is caused by differences in the terms language property.

When I count the terms in the taxonomy_term_data with the language set as 'und' it matches the total given by `taxonomy_get_tree($vid)`

When I count all terms in the taxonomy_term_data table regardless of language the total matches the the count given by `entity_load('taxonomy_term', FALSE, array('vid' => $vid))`

So if you only need terms in your current language go with taxonomy_get_tree($vid) otherwise you'll need entity_load().